# Get live user text input using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, github, google-chrome-extension, user-input

I'm trying to create a chrome extension which detects harmful social media posts before they go live (just like over here https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/137lLTunw2p6x7uefesHlBdUwL_pF8NbVeT1BFlUbs9E/edit#slide=id.g1d9c67055b_0_150. The thing is, i can't get the first step right, i.e getting user input as he types.

The repository (https://github.com/mollymolichen/lend-a-hand) uses the following code

`var textElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-text="true"]');`

`var userInput = textElements.innerHTML[0];`

But it doesn't work.

I have searched a lot and it doesn't look like it's possible. Can it be done? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
      $(":input").keyup(function() {
          val = $(this).val()
          if (val == /*harmfulText*/){
               //your logic
          }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did help me!

Comment: Hi, this only works for input fields. How do i use it for contenteditable div tags, like the one in twitter input box eg. <div data-offset-key="8k0it-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"><span data-offset-key="8k0it-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div>

Comment: maybe you can add some java script to code for this special cases like to chek the url of the page `window.location.href ` and if it twitter then select the div that is being written in by it's uniq class `public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr`and add event `onkeyup()`